# How do I contact EA about my battlelog problem?

Tags: battlefield-3, battlelog

I have had this problem for a long time now. I bought Battlefield 3 Premium Edition (game with premium code), and it doesn't say I'm premium on battlelog so I cant use the exclusive content.

In game I get the in-game content but not the strategy guides, videos, and artwork on battlelog.

How do I contact them?

Answer (score 1):

In the top-right corner of the [*battlelog*](http://battlelog.battlefield.com/) you have a link to the *forums*. Use it, you can ask your question there

Answer (score 0):

Go to the EA site and report a problem/ask a question. You can get a faster and more personal response from them if you say after the question or problem, when asked, that it was not resolved. It will give you an option to chat with someone and even have them call you. I have done both for problems I encountered in Battlefield 4. They were great and able to help each time. Even gave me a discount coupon on the second occurance of a problem!